# Cannot select rows from pandas dataframe after converting date to month using function .dt.to_period('M')

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe table like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"txn_id":{'A','B','C'},"txn_date":{'2019-04-01','2020-06-01','2021-05-01'})
```

I was trying to find rows where transaction month is 2021-05

so what i did was:

```
import datetime

df['txn_month'] = df['txn_date'].dt.to_period('M')

df[df['txn_month'] == '2021-05']
```

However, the result returns nothing, even though in table i could see column "txn_month" has "2021-05"

could you please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `dt.to_period`:

```
#convert to datetime if needed
df["txn_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["txn_date"])

>>> df[df["txn_date"].dt.to_period("m").eq("2021-05")]
  txn_id   txn_date
2      C 2021-05-01
```

Comment: Can i know why df[df["txn_date"].dt.to_period("m") == "2021-05"] doesn't work?

Comment: Your column is likely dates and not strings.